# Shopware 6 migration - custom field with entities not correctly migrated

Tags: migration, shopware, shopware6, shopware5

We are currently migrating a shop from Shopware 5.7.7 to Shopware 6.4.17.2 using these Shopware Plugins:

Shopware 6 Plugin (v4.2.5): https://store.shopware.com/swag257162657297f/migrations-assistent.html

Shopware 5 Plugin (v1.3.4): https://store.shopware.com/swag226607479310f/migration-connector.html

We have a problem with custom fields of type **Single selection - TEXT**.
In our case with entity type **Media - Shopware\Models\Media\Media** but we suspect that it occurs with all custom fields with an entity connection.

During the migration, a custom field of type **text** is created, with the id of the Shopware 5 entity as value.
These fields are unusable.

- The custom field has no label in the admin.
- The custom field has no value in the admin.
- The custom field does not allow entity selection with dropdown.
- The custom field has no link to an entity in Shopware 6.
- In case of an entity of type **Media - Shopware\Models\Media\Media** no image is imported.

Is there or will there be a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right, there is currently no migration of attributes of type `Single selection - TEXT`. These attributes should be migrated to the `Entity select` custom field type in SW6, but I couldn't find any ticket with this issue. Feel free to create a ticket for this, that the migration team could implement this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created a ticket: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/MIG-833